# IE9 stops at "looking for credential tiles..." dialog when using smartcard

Tags: certificate, smartcard

When I try to access secure page using smartcard I get  "looking for credential tiles..." dialog and IE stays there for ever. Only option is then to rebot PC.

After reboot I can always access the site for the first time but when I leave the site or logof and try to access it later it doesn't work and I need rebot.

I'm using Win7 32bit sp1

Comment: This sound like a problem unique to your computer.  Have you tried to use a different browser?  I understand your unlikely to have this ability.  Is this a pesonal or work PC?

Answer (score 2):

Check the list of Windows services. This can happen if a third party software has disabled the service "Credential Manager Service" (VaultSvc).

Start a command line with administrative permissions (Start, enter cmd and press Ctrl+Shift+Return) then type

```
net start VaultSvc
```

Afterwards retry accessing the secure page. The dialog "looking for credential tiles..." should be only visible for a short time now.

BTW: On German systems the error message is "Anmeldeinformationen werden gesucht.." and the service name is "Anmeldeinformationsverwaltung"

Answer (score 0):

Clicking "No", then doing Ctrl+Alt+Delete and then "Cancel" will get you out of this without a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

After applying Robert's answer you might want to try to remove the smartcard from the smartcard reader and then re-insert it again.